# What are the alignments referred to when discussing the strings section of a process address space

Tags: c, macos, kernel, exec

I'm trying to write a program to expose the arguments of other pids on macOS. I've made the `KERN_PROCARGS2` `sysctl`, but it turns out that everyone and their dog use this wrong. Including Apple's `ps`, and Google's Chrome. The `exec` family of functions all allow you to pass an empty string as `argv[0]`, which is not great but it can happen and so must be dealt with. In this case, the standard approach of skipping forward past the `NULL`s following the `exec_path` in the returned buffer doesn't work, as the last `NULL` before the rest of the arguments is actually the terminating `NULL` of an empty string, So you wind up skipping an argument you didn't mean to, which can result in printing an env var as an argument (I've confirmed this behaviour in many programs).

To do this properly one must calculate how many nulls to skip, instead of skipping them all every time. There are references around the web to the different parts of the returned buffer being pointer aligned, however no matter what part of the buffer I try to check with `len % 8` I don't get a correct count of padding `NULL`s.

- https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/main/bsd/kern/kern_sysctl.c#L1528
- https://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2012/Mar/msg00025.html
- https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/refs/heads/master/util/posix/process_info_mac.cc#153

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/sgnh/wmaker-crm/blob/5d643a67dd8156029ebcacbd15110929eef8dbb5/src/osdep_darwin.c

Comment: Do you mean `NULL` or NUL?

Comment: NUL i suppose, `00` bytes.

Comment: @TarunLalwani no, that implementation is wrong, it skips all the leading nulls without doing any checking if it's missing empty arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a library to do this correctly: https://getargv.narzt.cam